# Which Ubuntu desktop besides Unity can I drag rearrange taskbar icons?

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments

I really hate Unity, so I want another desktop experience, preferably one similar to Windows.
I have tried Lubuntu, Xubuntu, and Kubuntu, but why do these all feel so old? I cannot rearrange open taskbar tabs like I can in Windows 7. If you don't know what I'm talking about just think about your browser how easy you can rearrange the tabs, I want the same thing for the taskbar. But in Lubuntu and Xubuntu it stays locked and static; once opened it cannot move..

Are there any Ubuntu distributions that can drag open tabs around?

Answer (score 0):

Try Cinnamon.

[image]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

See here: [Cinnamon Installing tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-cinnamon.html) and [How-to- geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/103691/install-linux-mints-new-cinnamon-desktop-on-ubuntu/)